# How to make camera visibly rotate over time with button press in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

right now I have two buttons that rotate an orthographic cinemachine camera around my player, one clockwise 90 degrees and one counter-clockwise 90 degrees. The buttons' On Click () calls these two functions from a script on the camera, respectively:

```
  public void CameraRotateL()
  {
      if (PauseMenu.isPaused == false)
          transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.up, 90);
  }

  public void CameraRotateR()
  {
      if (PauseMenu.isPaused == false)
          transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.up, -90);
  }
```

This works perfectly, but I would like for the camera to visibly rotate through the 90 degrees over a short period of time when the button is clicked.
I have tried:

```
transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.up, (90/timeToRotate) * Time.deltaTime);
```

but the result is that the button moves the camera a tiny amount in one single frame.

I'm assuming I may need to use a Coroutine of some sort or something more complex than what I'm trying now, but hopefully this could be done without the use of a tweening library. Thank you in advance for any guidance!

I tried calculating the speed from the degrees and `timeToRotate` and multiplying that by `Time.deltaTime` but using a button to call this function only rotates the camera a small amount for one single frame, rather than smoothly rotating up to 90 degrees over a second, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a coroutine or use the `Update()` function to change the rotation gradually.

This method is correct, but you need to call it many times to work, because it changes the rotation contantly overtime:

```
transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.up, (90/timeToRotate) * Time.deltaTime);
```

One way of doing it is to set a target rotation when the object is clicked and then rotate gradually untill it is close enough of the target rotation

```
Vector3 startingRotation;
Vector3 targetRotation;
int timeCounter;
bool rotateToTarget = false;

public void CameraRotateL()
{
    if(PauseMenu.isPaused == false)
    {
        startingRotation = player.transform.rotation.Euler;
        targetRotation = player.transform.rotation.Euler + (Vector3.up * 90);     
        timeCounter = 0;
        rotateToTarget = true;
    }
}

public void CameraRotateR()
{
    if(PauseMenu.isPaused == false)
    {
        startingRotation = player.transform.rotation.Euler;
        targetRotation = player.transform.rotation.Euler + (Vector3.up * -90);     
        timeCounter = 0;
        rotateToTarget = true;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if(rotateToTarget)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.Euler(startingRotation), Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), timeCounter );
        timeCount = timeCount + Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
        if(transform.rotation == targetRotation) rotateToTarget = false;
    }
}
```

You can simplify the code not storing the startRotation and the targetRotation in Vector3, but in Quaternions. But I believe this way is easyer to understand

Comment: This definitely gave me something to work off of. Thank you.